# Are KeePassXC and KeePass Solaris-compatible?

Tags: solaris, compatibility, keepassx, keepassxc

I wanted to know whether [KeePassXC](https://keepassxc.org/) and [KeePass](https://keepass.info/) are compatible with Solaris (I am using Solaris 11.4.26.75.4 (sun4v / sparc architecture)). I would need to use only the KeePassXC/KeePass command line interfaces, the KeePassXC/KeePass GUIs are not necessary.

I do not have admin rights / sudo access, so I cannot install the software myself, but I may ask the responsible unix support team (which has admin access) to attempt the installation. However, before doing that, I wanted to ask regarding the Solaris compatibility here in the forum.

Under the respective download pages, Solaris is not listed among the supported OS.

**KeePassXC:** can be [built from source](https://github.com/keepassxreboot/keepassxc/blob/develop/INSTALL.md), but again Solaris is not included as a supported OS on the [Building KeePassXC wiki page (see Required Dependencies)](https://github.com/keepassxreboot/keepassxc/wiki/Building-KeePassXC).

**KeePass:** Googling yields a few links that might indicate Solaris compatibility ([Forbes article 1 (July 2023)](https://www.forbes.com/advisor/business/software/keepass-review/), [Forbes article (March 2023)](https://www.forbes.com/advisor/business/software/keepass-lastpass-comparison/), [KeePassX forum link](https://www.keepassx.org/index.html%3Fp=42.html)), but I am not 100% certain.

**Question: Can KeePassXC (preferred if possible) and/or KeePass be successfully built/installed from source and used on Solaris? Do you maybe know any tests/links explicitly giving this information?**

Comment: Honestly, why haven't you tried? Doesn't feel like installing the dependencies of KeepassXC is too convoluted. As soon as you hit a problem like "dependency XYZ is not available", you know it's not possible. (unless you feel like porting that dependency, also)

Comment: @MarcusMüller: Unfortunately, I do not have admin access / sudo rights, and wanted to know before asking the responsible unix support team to try. I updated the post to reflect this.

Comment: Is there no way to set up a Solaris VM on a personal system and see what it takes to build it? (ISTR once setting up such a VM but that was years ago, no idea what the case is now with Oracle.) Then you could even build the whole thing and and if ti works, just copy over the binary, required libraries and data files etc to the work system

Comment: At the very least, you can probably use `pkg` (or whatever package manager modern Solaris uses) to search for the dependencies! If you find something that's positively definitely not packaged, it will necessitate more than one source compilation. I'm sure your UNIX team will appreaciate the effort; but mayb just … ask them? They are getting paid for this, probably, and keeping their users' passwords safe probably is quite high on the priority list for admins, as having a single compromised user account is much work…